# Consolidate Table data into one

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have 4 different views, all that have their own table view with data. I want to make a 5th view/interface that has a table view that consolidates the other 4 tableview data into one.

For each of the 4 initial table views, I am storing the data using Core Data, and each table has its own entity with multiple attributes. Im looking for the theory about how to consolidate all these into one tableview. Any help would be great, or if you can point me in the right direction. 
So essentially i have 4 table views all with their own data, and i want to make a 5th table view that shows all the data.
Thanks so much!

Comment: The approach will mostly depend on the layout you want to achieve,  in general you can "merge" 4 `FRC`s with only a few adjustments at the standard code to wire up the index paths and `FRC`s data.

Comment: Your question is not clear. It would be helpful to understand how your table-views behave, are you adding data on any page to the table-view on the fly? are you preloading all table-views data in advance?. Also, is the layout different from one table-view to another ?

Comment: @Shachar Each table view cell is populated by input fields by the user with a text field and a slider. those values are then stored in each table view cell, all table views are the same in this sense. The merged table view would take the data just from the other four and populate the cells. In reality it looks like this its a baby journaled (feedings, diaper changes, naps, and bottle feeding). See next comment

Comment: Each activity has its own tableview in which the user can record that activity each time they do it. Each table view can be viewed to see when the last feeding or nap happened in the individual table view, however, i want a 5th view that shows all the activites that happened so you don't have to switch between views if you are only going to view the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what I would do is to store all the data of all the table views in a single mutable dictionary that contains sub dictionaries that contains each table view data like so:

```
MainDictionary >
---tableview1Dictionary
---tableview2Dictionary
---tableview3Dictionary
---tableview4Dictionary
```

I would save this dictionary on the NSUserDefaults so it can be accessed from each view controller in your app.

On the fifth view controller you can simply load this MainDictionary data in to your "combined" table view. This way whatever changes you make on any table view will directly effect your combined table view and all your data will be synced.

You can reload each table view on your controller **viewDidAppear**.

NSUserDefaults Tutorial: http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/10/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-savingretrieving-data-using-nsuserdefaults/

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for your help. So your way isn't using Core Data at all, am i correct in understanding this? Is there anyway to do this with Core Data, I'm trying to get a fuller understanding and knowledge of what i can do with Core Data.If this is not a possibility with Core Data, I'm cool with that, but i thought i would at least try with Core Data, since my existing tables are already using it.

Comment: Your right, this is not using Core Data. I guess if your aiming to learn CoreData in this project you might want to try some tutorial projects to get a good understanding of it. If you haven't seen this link already then this might help you: http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started